# How to add spring framork to eclipse in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, ubuntu

Hello I am new to Spring and Ubuntu.

I have set up eclipse kepler in ubuntu and I want to add Spring framework to eclipse but I did't understand the spring documentation and I cannot find the download link of framework. How can I add spring to eclipse.

As far as I know I have to download Spring Jar files and copy them to the classpath. However I couldn't download Spring

Comment: Have you ever use Maven? If not, try to use it.

Comment: I didn't use it, I was planning to use it after learning the Spring. Should I use it first?

Comment: @MasudCSECUET Why are you telling `OP` to use `Maven`?

Comment: @CodeEnthu, Becasue, this is easy and recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to  add Spring dependencies in your build path.

[image: BuildPath Configuration]

Check out this [tutorial.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_java_build_path.htm)

As per my experience with Spring, it depends upon multiple jars which is tedious to manage as described above. So, personally I use [Maven](http://spring.io/) as build dependency management tool. You can find lots of `POM.xml` example in Web for Spring, however [this pom.xml](https://github.com/TheKojuEffect/OpERP/blob/master/OpERP/pom.xml) is from one of my project in which I've used `Spring`.

Maven can be used for many aspects of build process as per your knowledge and if you're new to `Maven`, some basic guides and tutorials will do to use `Maven` as [build-dependency-management](http://spring.io/) tool.

It would be better if you use [Spring-Tool-Suite with your eclipse](http://spring.io/tools/eclipse) for productivity.

Spring's new site [Spring.io](http://spring.io/) is very helpful resource to learn Spring.

And Maven Plugin for Eclipse: [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/)

Comment: So Do I have to download files?

Comment: You'll have to download Spring dependencies manually if you're going to use first solution. And maven will download it for you automatically if you use second solution.

Comment: Thanks, I wil try it with maven :)

Answer (score 1):

[Download](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all) Spring Tool Suit IDE. Run some template project. These projects are maven based. This is the first step to learn and run Springframework for any OS (Windows, Ubuntu).

Comment: Thank You Masud, I am doing it.